# .remove not removing the given String

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
tweets = api.search(q="@mytwitter",count=100,include_entities=True)
t = ['@mytwitter', '@MyTwitter']

for s in tweets:
    sn = s.user.screen_name
    m = "@%s message" % (sn)
    s = api.update_status(m, s.id)
    #print(dir(s))

for result in tweets:
    print str(result.text)

for userName in result.text:
    if userName == "@mytwitter":
        result.text.remove(userName)
        print (userName)
    else:
        print("No username")
```

Not sure why userName isn't removing my Twitter name from result.text. Am I missing something? The output I'm getting is `"No username"` repeated a bunch of times.

If it helps the orginal output for result.text is `"@mytwitter their message"` I'm trying to remove the `@mytwitter.`

Comment: Plealse show your program output. Does result.text contains whole tweet, not just username?

Comment: @Diman I did include the output for result.text it contains the whole tweet and my username.

Comment: Is third *for* loop supposed to be inside the second one? Your indentaion seeems to be messed up

Comment: @Diman At first it was like that but it also didn't work so I just made it on its own.

Comment: @Dexter result.text is not a list. It is a string. So userName in the third loop is a character.

Comment: @Dexter If you do the second loop on its own, `result` is only the last tweet, not all the tweets.

Comment: And `for userName in result.text` loops over the characters in `result.text`, not the words.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the condition

```
if userName == "@mytwitter":
```

Is never true, so .remove() never called. If you want to *search* for your name inside the result.text, try this:

```
tweets = api.search(q="@mytwitter",count=100,include_entities=True)

for s in tweets:
    sn = s.user.screen_name
    m = "@%s message" % (sn)
    s = api.update_status(m, s.id)

for tweeet in tweets:
    if "@mytwitter" in tweeet.text:
        tweeet.text = tweeet.text.replace("@mytwitter", "")
        print(tweeet.text)
    else:
        print("No username")
```

p.s. The *str* object doesn't have .remove() method, try .replace() with empty string instead, as listed above.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, just tried that and no luck still displays my username in the tweet.

Comment: Just used the code you made and no luck again. Still shows my username in their tweet.

Comment: `.replace` does not replace characters in the original string.

Comment: @Psytho ok, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in Python so you have to assign your new string to another variable:

```
for tweet_text in tweets:
    if "@mytwitter" in tweet_text:
        new_str = tweet_text.replace("@mytwitter", "") # assigning new string wothout "@mytwitter" to another variable
        print(new_str)
    else:
        print("No username")
```

Example:

```
tweets = ["@mytwitter","1234","0987@mytwitter","@mytwitter145236","  @mytwitter12"]


for tweet_text in tweets:
    if "@mytwitter" in tweet_text:
        new_str = tweet_text.replace("@mytwitter", "") # assigning new string wothout "@mytwitter" to another variable
        print(new_str)
    else:
        print("No username")
```

Output:

```
No username

0987
145236
  12
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried out what you posted but I'm getting an error message saying "TypeError: argument of type 'Status' is not iterable"

Comment: You need to adapt the code to the objects you iterate over. What's your code new code now?